# EF multiple relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 5

So I have a Customer. The Customer could have many Addresses, but at least one. One of the addresses would also be set as the primary address (required). I tried various mappings, but so far I get an error on build or when I seed the database.

Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set;}
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; }
    public virtual CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }    
}
```

Address:

```
public class CustomerAddress : Address
{
    public int CustomerAddressId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

This part of my mapping is working correctly. It is on CustomerAddress.

```
        this.HasRequired(c => c.Customer)
            .WithMany(d => d.CustomerAddresses)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId);
```

But how do I specify the correct mapping for setting PrimaryAddress in Customer? Or is it the wrong approach?

Thanks

**EDIT - Using both Arnolds and LueTM's answers:**

This code is now working.

Customer:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set;}
    public String CustomerName { get; set; }
    // public int PrimaryAddressId { get; set; } created in mapping
    public virtual CustomerAddress PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }    
}
```

Address:

```
public class CustomerAddress : Address
{
    public int CustomerAddressId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Customer mapping:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>
            .HasOptional(c => c.PrimaryAddress)
            .WithOptionalDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("PrimaryAddressId"));

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>
            .HasMany(c => c.CustomerAddresses)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Customer)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CustomerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And I use a repository to make sure that a new address is created first, saved, and then also set as primary and saved again. The repository makes sure the primary is "required".

Comment: Please show the error and the piece of code where it occurs. (By editing your post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't show the exception, I have to assume that you ran into a chicken-egg problem.

If you set `PrimaryAddress` as a required property EF must have an existing address Id to establish the foreign key (set `PrimaryAddressId` in `Customer`). However, since `Address` requires a `Customer` you cannot store an address before its customer. And if you try to save an address and a customer in one take, EF can not determine the correct order of inserts, because it needs to insert both objects with the generated Id of the other object.

So either `Address` or `Customer` must have an optional foreign key.

I would make `Customer.PrimaryAddressId` optional:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().HasOptional(c => c.PrimaryAddress)
    .WithOptionalDependent();
```

Now you can store addresses and assign a primary address to a customer in separeate transactions. But you need business logic to ensure that a `Customer` always has a primary address.

If you want to save cutomers and addresses in one transaction, an approach could be to add an `IsPrimary` property (bool) to `CustomerAddress` and ensure that always exactly one address has `true`.

Comment: Yes this works. You are right, tried to do save both the address and assign it as primary in one transaction. Guess I was focussed too much about having the primary address "required". To wrap this up: It now generates its own forgeign key. Could I map this to my own "PrimaryAddressId"?

Comment: Solved that also. I removed PrimaryAddress id an instead added a mapping for it: 
this.HasOptional(c => c.PrimaryAddress)
                .WithOptionalDependent().Map(m => m.MapKey("PrimaryAddressId"));

Comment: Ah, didn't see your comment, but glad you found it!